# Why can't Mathematica maximize simple trigonometric Expression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, trigonometry

Explain please why such simple function won't be accomplished.

```
MaxValue[{a*Sin[x], a > 0}, x,Reals].
```

And how to solve this type tasks?

Comment: `MaxValue[{y,FunctionRange[{a*Sin[x],a>0},x,y]},y]`

Comment: @chyanog thanks!